# WebElement.sendKeys(CharSequence...) through Selenium sends only partial value

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys

Set value in the input element:

```
WebElement input = ...
input.sendKeys("1234989");
```

Sometimes, the input element only gets "1", not "1234989", any race condition here?

Another way:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.sendKeys(input, "1234989").build().perform();
```

This one seems works better. What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

The relevant HTML of the desired element would have helped us to debug why the desired element is populated only with **1** instead of **1234989**. However as per best practices, while sending a *character sequence* to an `input` field you should always induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` as follows:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("css_input_element"))).sendKeys("1234989");
```

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Send keys not working selenium webdriver python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770697/send-keys-not-working-selenium-webdriver-python/46773859#46773859)
- [Chrome webdriver send keys does not send '3'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47248275/chrome-webdriver-send-keys-does-not-send-3/47263704#47263704)

---

### `sendKeys(WebElement target, java.lang.CharSequence... keys)`

[sendKeys(WebElement target, java.lang.CharSequence... keys)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#sendKeys-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-java.lang.CharSequence...-) is from the `Actions` class and is equivalent to calling `Actions.click(element).sendKeys(keysToSend)`. This method is different from `WebElement.sendKeys(CharSequence...)`.

---

### `public Actions sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence... keys)`

[`public Actions sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence... keys)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#sendKeys-java.lang.CharSequence...-) sends a *CharSequence* to the **active element**. Again this differs from calling `WebElement.sendKeys(CharSequence...)` on the active element in two ways:

- The modifier keys included in this call are not released.
- There is no attempt to re-focus the element, so `sendKeys(Keys.TAB)` for switching elements should work.

You can find a detailed discussion in [When using Selenium's click_and_hold method exactly what conditions or actions cause the mouse click to release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55110926/when-using-seleniums-click-and-hold-method-exactly-what-conditions-or-actions-c/55303201#55303201)

Comment: Just tried. adding elementToBeClickable before sendKeys did not help. Is focus lost during sendKeys(...)?

Comment: `focus` once gained completely **isn't** lost until and unless you forcibly move away

Comment: maybe some ajax going on. have not found an effective way to wait after all ajax and related scripts are executed.